# Regex matching line with single " at the end

Tags: regex, csv, sed, regex-negation

I have a csv where all fields are enclosed by "". There are occasionally badly formatted lines of the form

> Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4"

with a variable number of fields. I need to delete these specific lines, avoiding all lines of the form

> "Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"

Comment: this should match the single hanging quote at the end `/^[^"]*"$/`

Comment: Thanks. I literally just found it as well. If you post the answer I'll accept yours.

Comment: No need, you can accept your own answer.  However, think whether a single `"` is acceptable on a record.  You may want to change `+` to `*`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just look for the following regex to match your line

```
^[^"]*"$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BtBQm9/1)**

This will look and match all the characters and match the `"` at the end of the line also.

If the first `"` is not at the end of the line, the line will not be matched.

Answer (score 1):

If the field content do not contain escaped quotes, you can test the
line for quote evenness.

If this matches, then delete the line:

`^(?![^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$).+$`

This can be adapted to account for escaped quotes as well.
Requires a bit more complex regex.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '/^\([^"]*\("[^"]*"\)*\)*$/!d' file
```

Delete the line unless it contains zero or more pairs of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

Using extended regex:

```
'/^[^"]+"$/'
```